# How to use query scope in join request Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following request:

```
$objects = Object::with("translate")->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
$query->language();

})->with('images')->with("category")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($limit);
```

So, in model `Object` there is method: `translate`:

```
public function translate()
{
   return $this->hasMany("App\ObjectTranslate", "objectId", "id");
}
```

So, also in this model is:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query)
    {
        $languageHeader = new ModelLibrary();

        return $query->where('language', '=', $languageHeader->getLanguage());
    }
```

When I try to call scope in main request:

```
$query->language();
```

I get SQL error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'language' in 'where clause' (SQL:
```

Comment: Column language is there in your Object modal's table

Comment: No, column `language` is in model `ObjectTranslate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the query with ObjectTranslate's table. your scopeLanguage() function will not work , since you are trying to access the column language which is not available in Object model column.

**Note** : With() will just eager loading, which will load the eloquent defined function, you cannot directly access their column in where clause.

Modify your scopeLanguage function

```
public function scopeLanguage($query)
{
    $languageHeader = new ModelLibrary();

    return $query->join('object_translate_table','object_translate_table.objectId','=','object_table.id')->where('object_translate_table.language',$languageHeader->getLanguage());

}

$objects = Object::with("translate","images","category") 
                   ->language() 
                   ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                   ->paginate($limit);
```

This should work

> Assumin ObjectTranslate model's table name is object_translate_table and Object model's table name is object_table

Comment: I need to use Closure, your answer is useful, but what can I do then?

Comment: Wait. I am updating again, just give me few minute

Comment: check the updated code, should work, if any issue happens then let me know

Comment: Thank you for work! How do you think, how to merge columns from some query scopes?

Comment: I mean replace result from main request on result from scope?

Comment: query scope is a powerful thing, now whenever you want to merge there two tables (mentioned in  question) you can use the language function with little modification. I always try to use scope in my code